Android Location Foreground Service Clean architecture
I am programming an application which tracks the users location in a foreground service and processes the location data further. Since I want to use a clean architecture (presentation, domain, data -layers) for my application, i am asking myself in which layer i should put the service.
I would like to consider the collected location data as a data source but I dont know how to start/stop the location from the data layer or how to get the data out of the service.
In my previous design I started the service from an activity and send the data via a broadcast.
Do you have any ideas on that? Thank you:)
